# Angular Subscribe Return Value In Property

Tags: angular, typescript

I need Use Value From Subscribe and Use on Property For Return DateTime But I don't know how To Use

Component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();

    let defautWIPEndTime = this.service.getDefautWIPEndTime().subscribe(res => {});

    console.log(defautWIPEndTime);

  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {

    if (form != null)
      form.form.reset();

    this.service.plan = {
      Id: 0, 
      Name: '',
      Description: '',      
      CreatedOn: this.defautWIPEndTime ,

    }
  }
```

Subscribe Return
`{$id: "20", DefautWIPEndTime: "17:30:00"}`

I Need Put Value `17:30:00` on Property `CreatedOn`

= What I Need =

```
    this.service.plan = {
      Id: 0, 
      Name: '',
      Description: '',      
      CreatedOn: 17:30:00, <=======================
    }
```

I have Other Question How Subscribe return Just Time. Now It Return On Object

= Now Result =

```
    this.service.plan = {
      Id: 0, 
      Name: '',
      Description: '',      
      CreatedOn: {$id: "20", DefautWIPEndTime: "17:30:00"}, <=======================
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the result from subscripe is just a date, then you just set it withing the subscribtion.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();

    this.service.getDefautWIPEndTime().subscribe(res => {
      this.service.plan.CreatedOn= res;
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now Object from subscribe Is in `this.service.plan.CreatedOn` Now

Comment: I have other question It can return just a date on component.ts Or not

Comment: Yes it can return anything whatever logic you write it to return